# How to center modal window in css+html?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

How to center vertical modal window with such css style:

```
.inquiry_form_container {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -375px;
  width: 750px;
  top: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #cccccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #cccccc;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #cccccc;
}
```

it's has a non known height, how to do, that that window will be with same margins from top and bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have the right idea using `left:50%` but I would use 2 DIVs. One inside the other:

The first DIV would have `position:relative`,`left:50%` and `width:0px`.

The second DIV (inside) would have `position:absolute`, `width:200px` and `left:-100px`.

Not sure what to do about the unknown height. How about a pixel height on the second DIV and use `overflow-y:scroll`?